# Scala regex for line splitting with pipe delimitor

Tags: regex, scala

Here is the string I am trying to convert into the lines by using Scala regex

```
3156|4|20150701000000||2.773|||||||||||7094|20150728000000|3156|4|20150801000000||2.821|||||||||||7094|20150728000000|3156|4|20150901000000||2.816|||||||||||7094|20150728000000|3156|4|20151001000000||2.845|||||||||||7094|20150728000000|3156|4|20151101000000||2.962|||||||||||7094|20150728000000|
```

Split is needed after every 17th pipe

Tried following but didn't work, any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
""""[\\||\\.?\\|]{17}""".r
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((?:[^|]*\\|){17})
```

You can split by this.Just remove the empty parts.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/58

Answer (score 0):

Do matching instead of splitting,

```
(?:[^|]*\|){1,17}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bY5zP8/1)